# Extract substring that starts with any letter

Tags: python

I have a set of strings and want to extract the portion that starts with a A-Z letter. I'm having issues since the position of the first letter is variable.

Example list:

```
2C559EQ2_7_N001
0659AA_LNODE10A
93AFTS_LNODE131
AF_2_UNIT4GNODE
```

Expected output

```
EQ2_7_N001
AA_LNODE10A
AFTS_LNODE131
AF_2_UNIT4GNODE
```

Comment: There's a C in your first string. Did you want that part of the string?

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using regex:

```
import re
x = re.search(r'[A-Z].*', "0659AA_LNODE10A").group(0)
print(x)
```

print yields `AA_LNODE10A`.
Explanation: `[A-Z]` matches any letter between A-Z. `.*` matches any character 0 or more times. In combination, this matches the first appearance of a letter A-Z, followed by any character until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`finditer`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) to find the first occurrence of any uppercase alphabet and use string slicing to obtain the final string.

**Note:** If the string does not contain any alphabet then a `StopIteration` exception is raised.

```py
import re

samples = [
    "2C559EQ2_7_N001",
    "0659AA_LNODE10A",
    "93AFTS_LNODE131",
    "AF_2_UNIT4GNODE",
]

regex = re.compile(r"[A-Z]")
filtered_samples = [
    sample[next(regex.finditer(sample)).start() :] for sample in samples
]
print(filtered_samples)
```

Output:

```
['C559EQ2_7_N001', 'AA_LNODE10A', 'AFTS_LNODE131', 'AF_2_UNIT4GNODE']
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at each character to see if it meets your criteria then slice the string at that point.

```
s = '0659AA_LNODE10A'
for i,c in enumerate(s):
    if not c.isalpha():
        continue
    break
print(s[i:])


i = 0
while not s[i].isalpha():
    i += 1
print(s[i:])
```